# after the word project we use *on* or *in*?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> +5 years of experience in **project management** *on* environmental field

Question: is it correct to use *on* after **project management** in the example above?

Comment: nope, it's "exprience in project management" and "project management in a field", thus "experience in project management in the environmental field".. For future reference: "in a field", "on a topic"

Comment: What research have you conducted? Are there any more examples or context?

Comment: @Born2Smile Thank you! so if I delete the field and just say "experience in project management on environment", "on environment" here  should be correct?

Comment: it would be "on the environment" or "in the environmental field", however Sakatox' suggestion "experience in environmental project management" is probably even better

Answer (score 2):

Definitely **not valid, or correct.**

"+5 years of experience..." to me, indicates that there is something before the +5. Correction: "5+ years of experience...", which means more than 5 years."

If this is a fragment, and you mean 5 years of exp in something, then just write that. "5 years of experience...".

You can only get experience from, and in, or with/about.
About is less common.

"5 years of experience in [something]"
[something] -> environmental project management if i understand right.

You can also only be *in* a field/business/etc, on a field would mean you encompass the field and are placed on top of it - or speaking of the field as a whole. Semantically speaking you can only be *in* something abstract, like the idea of a field in relation with experience. Imagine experience as a single point in a gigantic field of points. You have a lot of that.

**In.**

You could always rephrase it a bit, and say
*"5+ years of experience in the field of environmental project management."*

Comment: Than you for your detailed explanation, I need to mention that my field of study is environment, not project management. In the context of environment, you can do different task such as project management, project analysis, and so on. Therefore, I'd rather separate the the environmental field from project management, from other hand i 'd like to emphasis on project management first, then bring up the area of study which is environment. So, perhaps i could say "5+ years of experience in project management on environment" ?

Comment: No, even in that case, it would still be "in" environment. Consider environment as a category/business.